# Optimal Number of Categories for Users to Choose from in a Dropdown

Tags: usability, dropdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Optimum number of choices for menus/navigation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8377/optimum-number-of-choices-for-menus-navigation)

If on a site, a user needs to put their post into a particular category before they submit, how many choices is too many? What would be the maximum cap before it got confusing?

Comment: You may want to checkout this question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8377/optimum-number-of-choices-for-menus-navigation

Comment: I don't see anything significantly different between this and the linked question; if you have a more specific question go ahead and edit your post and let me/us know in a comment and we can reopen

Answer (score 1):

Avoid scrolling. That's the only hard rule... if the user can't see some of the choices they may not know it is possible. This is also important because scrolling a drop down works differently on various platforms, and often works very poorly. The drop down list should never be taller than a single screen if you can avoid it.

But this is not always possible... a common use case that violates this is selecting your State on a form. When possible, encourage users to select by typing... the javascript tool [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) is a nifty improvement on drop down usability with very little downsides. It degrades cleanly if they have Javascript disabled, and requires no server side support.